# Replace Only Integer Values with a sequence of consecutive numbers in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I replace only the integer values in the ID column with a sequence of consecutive numbers?  I'd like any non-integer or NaN cells skipped.

Current df:

```
       ID   AMOUNT
        1   0.00
     test   5.00
test test   0.00
     test   0.00
        1   0.00
       xx   304.95
     x xx   304.95
        1   0.00
        1   0.00
    xxxxx   0.00
        1   0.00
      xxx   0.00
    xx xx   0.00
        1   0.00
```

Desired Outcome:

```
       ID   AMOUNT
        1   0.00
     test   5.00
test test   0.00
     test   0.00
        2   0.00
       xx   304.95
     x xx   304.95
        3   0.00
        4   0.00
    xxxxx   0.00
        5   0.00
      xxx   0.00
    xx xx   0.00
        6   0.00
```

I tried making a new column using np.arange(len(df)) and then replacing the ID values with that, but it's not giving me the expected outcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['ID'] = (pd
   .to_numeric(df['ID'], errors='coerce')  # convert to numeric
   .cumsum()                               # increment numbers
   .convert_dtypes().astype(object)        # back to integer
   .fillna(df['ID'])                       # restore non-numeric
)
```

Alternative using slicing and updating:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors='coerce')
df['ID'].update(s[s.notna()].cumsum().astype(int).astype(object))
```

output:

```
           ID  AMOUNT
0           1    0.00
1        test    5.00
2   test test    0.00
3        test    0.00
4           2    0.00
5          xx  304.95
6        x xx  304.95
7           3    0.00
8           4    0.00
9       xxxxx    0.00
10          5    0.00
11        xxx    0.00
12      xx xx    0.00
13          6    0.00
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Solution 1

Identify numeric values with regex then create a range counter and use boolean indexing to update the values

```
m = df['ID'].str.match('\d+', na=False)
df.loc[m , 'ID'] = range(1, m.sum() + 1)
```

##### Solution 2

Identify numeric values with pandas builtin function then create a range counter and use boolean indexing to update the values

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors='coerce').notna()
df.loc[m , 'ID'] = range(1, m.sum() + 1)
```

Result

```
           ID  AMOUNT
0           1    0.00
1        test    5.00
2   test test    0.00
3        test    0.00
4           2    0.00
5          xx  304.95
6        x xx  304.95
7           3    0.00
8           4    0.00
9       xxxxx    0.00
10          5    0.00
11        xxx    0.00
12      xx xx    0.00
13          6    0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can iterate over the ID-column this can be done easily via pythons `isinstance(object, class)` function.

```
count = 0
for index, value in enumerate(df['ID']): # Iterate over the column
    if isinstance(value, int): # Check if this is an integer
        df['ID'][index] = count # Replace integer
        count += 1
        pass
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm getting multiple 1s in my column and it also replaces some strings with integers for some reason, might have to do with actual data vs sample I provided... The answer below worked though.